# Draw a curve defining the bounds of a scatter plot to detect anomalous (sparse or low density) points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, scatter-plot, outliers, kernel-density

I have thousands of x,y data paris of observed and theoretical temperatures in a given region, where I need to identify some anomalous (for the purpose of my work) data points. I have tried PCA analysys (i.e., DBSCAN), statistical thresholds, curve fittings, etc., but none of them did work. I then tried a KDE-based approach, which seems to 'better' work for my data. To achieve the results shown below I used https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8430-flow-cytometry-data-reader-and-visualization as:

```
[hAxes,col,ctrs1,ctrs2,F] = dscatter(X,Y,'BINS',[250,250]);
% Please note, I modified the code to export hAxes,col,ctrs1,ctrs2 and plot the contour line as:
contour(ctrs1,ctrs2,F,0.0015,'k-'); % or 0.015 ---> See figure below
```

By using this apporach I was able to draw a contour line around the main cluster of my data, and I was mostly able to draw the line between 'main cluster' and 'anomalous' points. However, if I have too many 'anomalous' data points (**see xy4** in the figure below), the method, using a fixed threshold, fails. Beside, I have to adjust the threshold based on the region of each x,y pair and I have no idea on how to find the correct threshold level (see the figure below - For the same region, a threshold level of 0.0015 seems to work for situations with a few anomalous points, but a threshold of 0.015 is needed when more spreaded points occurred).

What I would really like to do is to draw a curve around the main cluster of my scatterplot, so to devide the anomalous data points. I fully understand this may be a challenging task, but I hope you may provide some good alternatives and/or solutions.

Another solution, as it seems to work, may be defining automatically the density threshold level, but I don't really know where to start from.

Below, you can see 4 examples (**xy 1 to 4 are attached**
note col1 and col2 = xy1 - col3 and col4 = xy2, etc. You can find the data here: https://www.mashupstack.com/share/64fc9e4fb3683).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keJen.jpg)

To the left is the simple x,y scatterplot. In the middle, the **ideal curve (in red)** defining the boundary of my scatterplot (manually sketched). To the right, the KDE-based approach discussed above. **Please note** the last figure where a threshold of 0.0015 fails, and a threshld of 0.015 is needed instead.

Any help is grately appreciated!

**Any other approach** to identify the points outside the red boundaries is more than wellcome!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578452/removing-outliers-before-fitting-convex-hull) - note a keyword which might help your search is "convex hull"